# How to get oauth access_token with jQuery (localhost)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oauth-2.0, mime

I am trying to get access_token utilizing jQuery. Problem is, that I cannot get that token (server is running on localhost). Server works fine (I tried that with postman), but I cannot get it with jQuery.
Browser writes after clicking on the button.

The resource from “http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?callback=jQuery34105901959820360243_1562175129954&grant_type=password&client_id=my-client&client_secret=my-secret&username=test%40seznam.cz&password=Peter&_=1562175129955” was blocked due to MIME type (“application/json”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

jQuery function to get access_token

```
function authenticateUser(email, password) {
    var body = {
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: 'my-client',
        client_secret: 'my-secret',
        username: "test@seznam.cz",
        password: "Peter"
    };


    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/token',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        header: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
        data: body,
        complete: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        },

        success: function(result) {
            alert(result + " OK!");
        },

        error: function(result) {
            alert(result + " CHYBA");
        },
    });
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the javascript file is served by the same server that gives out the tokens then there's no need to use the full url in your jquery ajax code (and there's no need to indicate crossDomain=true). It also seems that your server is expecting json content type instead of url-encoded

use

```
        url: '/oauth/token',
        crossDomain: false,
...
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
```

To make the request

---

## Edit

Trye this way:

```
   $.post("/oauth/token",body,
  function(data, status) {
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: /oauth/token wrote CORS problem. When I used the whole url, it returns this:

Comment: {"error":"method_not_allowed","error_description":"Request method &#39;GET&#39; not supported"}

Comment: Have you changed the code recently? That error sounds like you're performing a GET request to the server when it's expecting another verb (like POST or PUT). Does the server perform another request?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the $.post jquery method example. Try that

Comment: I tried for endpoints which do not need access_token and it works... but unfornatuely, not for getting those tocken s:( I tried your solution and I have problem with CORS again... :/

Comment: I am getting this response...timestamp 2019-07-03T18:33:32.251+0000
status 401
error Unauthorized
message Unauthorized
path /oauth/token

Comment: It really writes "Unauthorized 401" for every request to oauth/token :(

Comment: Zaragoza ok i tried to download CORS everywhere to my browser and I tried the same request as postman does and it works... but if I did not use that plugin to browser, it would not work again... and i would really need it to working without that plugin :/

Comment: Did you write the server logic? It sounds like there is a filter or middleware set for /oauth/token url. Perhaps you need another token (llike a jwt) first before getting the oauth token.

Comment: I did. I should not need that... It should be enough to use client-id, client-secret, username and password (as I did in postman) and then I should get that token...